# Button does not fire on gridview?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms

My vb.net program with a gridview has a very complex variable query based on selections from a prior prog so the datasource code is in the codebehind as well as various private functions for the template fields:

```
Dim SqlDataSource1 As New SqlDataSource()
SqlDataSource1.ID = "SqlDataSource1"
Me.Page.Controls.Add(SqlDataSource1)
SqlDataSource1.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("NativePlantsTESTConnectionString").ConnectionString
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = TheQuery  'built elsewhere & populated in this prog
Me.gvPlantList.DataSource = SqlDataSource1
Me.gvPlantList.DataBind()
```

The button code on listplants.aspx:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnPrint" runat="server" Text="Print-Ready Selected Plants" />
```

and in the codebehind:

```
Protected Sub btnPrint_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnPrint.Click
    Dim SessName, Dest As String
    Me.lblErrMsg.Visible = False
    Dim Ctr As Integer
    Dim TheToken As String 
    For Each row As GridViewRow In gvPlantList.Rows
        If row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
            Dim cbRow As CheckBox = TryCast(row.Cells(0).FindControl("cbPrint"), CheckBox)
            If cbRow.Checked Then
                Ctr = Ctr + 1
                If Ctr > 10 Then
                    Me.lblErrMsg.Text = "TOO MANY PLANTS - Currently limited to 10"
                    Me.lblErrMsg.Visible = True
                    Exit Sub
                End If
                TheToken = CType(row.Cells(4).FindControl("lblToken"), Label).Text
                SessName = "Print" & Ctr 
                Session(SessName) = TheToken
            End If
        End If
    Next
    If Ctr = 0 Then
        Me.lblErrMsg.Text = Me.lblErrMsg.Text & "Please check the plants you wish to print, up to 10 max"
        Me.lblErrMsg.Visible = True
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dest = "printcards.aspx"
    Response.Redirect(Dest)
```

When the selection prog gets to the list prog to show the results, there's a standard asp button on it to allow display of selected items. However, the button does not fire in IE8 or 11, but it works fine in the Visual Studio debugger, Chrome and Firefox. I've read most of the relevant questions here, but have not seen this one.

I added temporary postback check code (I thought I'd read somewhere that postbacks don't always work correctly with gridviews, but could be wrong), and a temporary label on the aspx to show what's happening has correct "first time in" and "is postback" displays. I see correct values in everything except IE, where it never gets beyond "first time in".

What's interesting is that as far as I can tell, this only happens on our webserver here, and it works correctly in IE for others from outside, leading me to think there's something on our server here that's affecting this. Someone else suggested that a change on our proxy server may have made it so that IE is getting a cached page for the initial hit to the page, but then the postbacks aren't able to get through because of some new rule, but if that were the case, would that only affect a gridview page? The initial selection page buttons work fine so that kinda makes sense.

The site is http://www.albemarle.org/nativeplantstest and the program that fails for us is listplants.aspx if anyone wants to try it.

Thanks!
elaine

Comment: So I asked our systems guy about that cached page thing, his response was "I disabled output caching for aspx files per your request." Unfortunately that didn't fix my problem. <sigh>

Comment: Edit your question and add the code of your button. Also, verify if you are getting any javascript errors at client side (browser).

Comment: No javascript errors in the client

Comment: Further research suggested that if there is only a single (or none?) text boxes on a form, in IE it may not fire the button, although Chrome and FF will. This program has no textboxes (only checkboxes) so I added two invisible text boxes to it, but that did not fix the problem. I should also  note all of my programs are 100% VB, there is no javascript, at least that I manually created.